# Comparing two directories to produce output

Tags: bash, unix, diff

I am writing a Bash script that will replace files in folder A (source) with folder B (target). But before this happens, I want to record 2 files.

- The first file will contain a list of files in folder B that are newer than folder A, along with files that are different/orphans in folder B against folder A
- The second file will contain a list of files in folder A that are newer than folder B, along with files that are different/orphans in folder A against folder B

How do I accomplish this in Bash? I've tried using `diff -qr` but it yields the following output:

```
Files old/VERSION and new/VERSION differ
Files old/conf/mime.conf and new/conf/mime.conf differ
Only in new/data/pages: playground
Files old/doku.php and new/doku.php differ
Files old/inc/auth.php and new/inc/auth.php differ
Files old/inc/lang/no/lang.php and new/inc/lang/no/lang.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php and new/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php and new/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php and new/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php differ
```

I've also tried this

```
(rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/ && rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" new/ old/) | sort | uniq
```

but it doesn't give me the scope of results I require. The struggle here is that the data isn't in the correct format, I just want files not directories to show in the text files e.g:

```
conf/mime.conf
data/pages/playground/
data/pages/playground/playground.txt
doku.php
inc/auth.php
inc/lang/no/lang.php
lib/plugins/acl/remote.php
lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php
lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php
```

Comment: Please update the body of your Q in reference to Git bash. Please don't rely on additional comments to make your problem description complete/clear. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of files in directory B (`new/`) that are newer than directory A (`old/`):

```
find new -newermm old
```

This merely runs `find` and examines the content of `new/` as filtered by `-newerXY reference` with `X` and `Y` both set to `m` (modification time) and `reference` being the `old` directory itself.

Files that are missing in directory B (`new/`) but are present in directory A (`old/`):

```
A=old B=new
diff -u <(find "$B" |sed "s:$B::") <(find "$A" |sed "s:$A::") \
  |sed "/^+\//!d; s::$A/:"
```

This sets variables `$A` and `$B` to your target directories, then runs a unified `diff` on their contents (using [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to locate with `find` and remove the directory name with `sed` so `diff` isn't confused).  The final `sed` command first matches for the additions (lines starting with a `+/`), modifies them to replace that `+/` with the directory name and a slash, and prints them (other lines are removed).

Here is a bash script that will create the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: bash script.bash OLD_DIR NEW_DIR [OUTPUT_FILE]
# compare given directories

if [ -n "$3" ]; then # the optional 3rd argument is the output file
  OUTPUT="$3"
else # if it isn't provided, escape path slashes to underscores
  OUTPUT="${2////_}-newer-than-${1////_}"
fi

{
  find "$2" -newermm "$1"
  diff -u <(find "$2" |sed "s:$2::") <(find "$1" |sed "s:$1::") \
    |sed "/^+\//!d; s::$1/:"
} |sort > "$OUTPUT"
```

First, this determines the output file, which either comes from the third argument or else is created from the other inputs using a replacement to convert slashes to underscores in case there are paths, so for example, running as `bash script.bash /usr/local/bin /usr/bin` would output its file list to `_usr_local_bin-newer-than-_usr_bin` in the current working directory.

This combines the two commands and then ensures they are sorted.  There won't be any duplicates, so you don't need to worry about that (if there were, you'd use `sort -u`).

You can get your first and second files by changing the order of arguments as you invoke this script.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful!